# Descobrir se activity foi fechada

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Boa noite! Sou iniciante em android e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de chat onde dois usuários se conectam através de uma fila com base nas preferências escolhidas. Quando um dos usuários se desconectar do chat (encerrar a activity) eu quero salvar o status no firebase para informar ao outro usuário que a pessoa com quem ele estava conversando saiu conversa.

Como posso verificar se minha activity foi destruída ou não?
Eu testei utilizar uma variável boleana com nome de ativo e setar ela como trrue em onStart e false em onDestroy. Também tentei usar o método isDestroyed para ver se a activity foi encerrada. Mas estou falhando nisso.

Eu não sei em que local eu faço essa verificação para testar o valor dessas variáveis booleanas. Tentei fazer a checagem no onStart mas não funcionou. O que eu devo fazer? Abaixo estão os métodos que fiz.

```js
public boolean appAberto(){
        //Se foi destruido retorna false, se esta aberto retorna true
        if (ChatPrivadoActivity.this.isDestroyed()){
            //retorna true se foi destruido
            //isFinishing Verifica se a activity esta em procersso de finalização
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "ENCERROU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Chamei essa função no onStart e não retornou nada mesmo depois de eu fechar a activity. Depois tentei isso:

```js
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        recuperarMensagensConversa();
        ativo = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
       ativo = false;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ativo = false;
    }
```

Mas não tive sucesso porque eu não soube exatamente onde testar essa variável que criei. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Coloca essa variavel boolean apenas em onResume e no onPause, onResume verdadeiro e no onPause falso, acredito que funcione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a maneira mais simples de funcionar, baseado no [Ciclo de Vida da Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-BR#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks). é a seguinte:

Adicione o método onResume

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Aqui você pode recuperar os dados do chat caso tenha
    //e enviar pro seu database que a Activity está ativa
}
```

O método onResume sempre é chamado quando inicia uma activity ou quando o estado da activity que for pausada, parada ou destruída for resumida.

Adicione o método onPause

```
   protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Aqui você pode salvar informações do chat no seu database
        //e enviar pro database que a Activity não está em uso

    }
```

o onPause é sempre chamado quando o usuário fecha a aplicação, fica em background, outra activity é iniciada, a activity é destruída...

Comment: Muito obrigada! Funcionou para mim. Eu setei "ativo = false" em onPause como você indicou e dentro do método onDestroy eu fiz uma verificação para atualizar o valor dentro do firebase e assim consegui notificar ao usuário que o outro usuário(com quem ele estava conversando) fechou a janela de bate papo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu achei uma forma melhor de detectar se o app foi fechado pelo usuário. Usei os métodos isfinishing e isDestroyed dentro do método onStop.

```
   @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (ChatPrivadoActivity.this.isFinishing() || ChatPrivadoActivity.this.isDestroyed()){           

            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "onStop-fechou o app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            finish();            
    }
}
```